# How to run second task only when karma test task is successful with Gulp?

Tags: gulp, gulp-karma

I am using Gulp. I have a `deploy` task that runs after `test` task. The problem is that `deploy` task runs even if test failed. Is there a way to run `deploy` task only when tests are successful in gulp?

```
gulp.task('test', function() {
  return gulp.src('some_test_tile')
    .pipe(karma({
      configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
      action: 'run'
    }));
});

gulp.task('deploy', ['test'], function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.scripts)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest));
});
```

I am using `gulp-karma` to run Karma tests.

Comment: What testing framework are you using with karma? Is it possible to make your framework throw an exception when a test fails? I believe that would stop subsequent gulp tasks from running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [gulp-karma example](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-karma) says to add .on('error', ...) after the pipe to karma, and manually throw the error to ensure gulp exits non-zero if any tests fail. That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Are your tasks running before the dependencies are complete? Make sure your dependency tasks are correctly using the async run hints.

Tasks can be made asynchronous if its `fn` does one of the following:

- Accept a callback
- Return a stream
- Return a promise

See example on [API documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#deps)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

// takes in a callback so the engine knows when it'll be done
gulp.task('one', function (cb) {
    // do stuff -- async or otherwise
    cb(err); // if err is not null and not undefined, the run will stop, and note that it failed
});

// identifies a dependent task must be complete before this one begins
gulp.task('two', ['one'], function () {
    // task 'one' is done now
});

gulp.task('default', ['one', 'two']);
```